# I want to prepare my data for Survival analysis modelling

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, survival-analysis

Like this we have 500 entries. Entries may be repeated.

[image]

The date represents the date on which that particular car part(carparts) was malfunctioning. We have to predict on which date a car part(carparts) is going to malfunction.

Codes are written in R. The code to develop the table is mentioned below:-

```
     q<-c("Mercedes","Audi","Tata","Renault","Ferrari","Lamborgini")
    w<-sample(q,500,replace=TRUE)

    m <- c("accelerator", "gear", "coolant", "brakes", "airbags")
    k <- sample(m, 500, replace=TRUE)

    e <- seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2011/1/1"), by="days")
    l <- sample(e, 500, replace=TRUE)

   test <- list(w,k, l)
   t2   <- as.data.frame(test)
   names(t2) <- c("carnames","carparts", "date")

   t2$Diffdate<-as.numeric(t2$date-as.Date("2010-01-01"))
   head(t2)
```

I'm preparing my data for survival analysis .In the code above I haven't included the censor and event variable .(I tried a rough draft and it went messy.) I just need an idea of how to include the event and censor variable along with the carparts variable and carnames variable. I'm getting stuck as I'm unable to frame all the variables in a single table.

Two problems that I'm facing are:-

1> I can't find a way to keep carparts ,carnames,event and censor variable in one table.

2> And the event variable is always 1 in each entry because for each entry(row) there is a breakdown/defect of carparts happening.Is it ok to have so?

As in all the examples I saw from internet the event variable had both ones and zeroes.

**Edited 1:-** Its not necessary to do it in R, you may write it down (draw the table including the columns present as well as the censor and event variable) on a piece of paper and attach the snapshot.

Thanks

Comment: Survival analysis requires information about the non-malfuncitoning enities as well. Look up the improper statistical analysis of the O-ring data leading up to the Challenger disaster if you want to see what happens when this principle is not appreciated. Your data has no unique identifier for where these failures occurred (which cars) and therefore has no predictors that might be interesting as covariates. I think you need statistical help before you are reading for coding.

Comment: As per your feedback ,I've added a new column carnames .Open to further suggestions/solutions. Thanks for the help

Comment: In order to do survival analysis there needs to be information sufficient to determine the length of time an individual part or car has been "exposed to risk of failure". With the sort of data presented so far, I don't see any hope of that. You might be able to estimate the proportion of a particular car part's needing to be restocked based on other features like the year of the car or the model but that's not really "survival analysis".

Comment: First of all thanks for your valuable guidance .As per my new edit I've taken 2010-01-01 as base date and subtracted the malfunctioning date from that .Thats how I have made a new column Diffdate which shows the duration of time after which the part started malfunctioning. Is it good to go? Other suggestions are welcomed too

Comment: @42 To view the new table which includes the Diffdate , please click on the image link in the problem description at the top. Also  provided here https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VBV2.png

Comment: Your two questions seem to be answered. (1) the table you show know has carname, carpart, event variable (always 1 in your data), censor variable (opposite of event variable - always 0 in your data), and the other needed variable, time to event/censoring. So you have worked that out. (2) As per 42's second comment, no - it is not okay to have data only on the failures. (Unless you just happened to observe everything to completion - but experiencing an event should not be a necessary condition to be in your data set.)

Comment: Hi @Gregor .. Thanks for your valuable input. I got your first point clearly . But in the 2nd point I do find certain apprehensions. I didn't get you completely in the 2nd point  . I want to ask you certain questions to get it clarified.  Is it ok to have all the event variables as 1 or something is needed to be done to change that? If its not ok to have all the event variables as 1  , then what possibly  could be done to make my dataset ready for survival analysis?

Comment: @42 - would you possibly have a definitive reference (quality journal, peer reviewed, etc.) on the rights and wrongs of the technical aspects of statistical analysis you mentioned on the Challenger disaster. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Presidential-Commission-Shuttle-Challenger-Accident/dp/999739769X

Comment: As for free primers on survival analysis, [I think this appendix by John Fox is pretty good](https://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion-1E/appendix-cox-regression.pdf).

Comment: Also look at the page labeled 359 in https://history.msfc.nasa.gov/book/chptnine.pdf . That was the chart I was remembering from the post-mortem analysis.

Comment: What really matters on this particular point is the selection criteria for how subjects are selected for inclusion in your model. If there is a large population of subjects but you only include in your data the ones that fail, then your estimates will be very biased toward failure and you won't be able to generalize to the greater population. This is bad. The usual (good) case is that your sample is selected independent of failure and at the time you do the study you have some observations that failed and some that did not (censored)  You have information on both failures and not-yet-failed.

Comment: The exception is when you're able to wait long enough that everything failed. If I did a survival analysis of people born in the year 1800, none are left alive so I would have no censoring, all subjects have experienced the death event. But this is not due to selection bias, it is due to the length of my follow-up time. In this case it is good - I have complete information. I don't know how cars/parts are chosen for inclusion in your data, but my guess is that you only have information on failures.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to supplement your data? For example, your first row has a Ferrari with brakes that failed after 345 days. Maybe you know that at 345 days that Ferrari's gear, accelerator, coolant, etc. had not failed and you could add those rows as censored at 345 days? That could help. But maybe you can't - maybe the row 13 Ferrari is the same as the row 1 Ferrai. Or maybe those parts could have broken in between and not be included in yoru data. I don't know your data, so I can't answer those questions.